# how to Dual boot win 7 and ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot

i am currently using win 7 and am planning on installing ubuntu alongside win7 but i have unable to do so.
Previously i used to install ubuntu inside win using wubi but this time i wanted it as a native os .
I have a 500 gb hd.
c: win 7 (71gb capacity)
d: some stuff (289gb capcaity )
e: (98 gb capcaity )
i want to install it in e drive. since it is having free space so it shrank the vol and created an un allocated space of 35gb for installing.
while in ubuntu install process i choose something else and tried to choose 35gb partiton as to create root,boot and home partitions it wont select.
all the drives c,d,f are in ntfs ...even while formatting wont show anyother option except ntfs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic disk can only have 4 primary partitions. If you already have 3 primaries defined, Ubuntu may not have enough to work with. I'm pretty sure Ubuntu needs to create at *least* two in order to function. On a basic disk, it might even need 3 - one for root, one for boot, and one for swap.

Remove that E: drive partition (once you've moved everything off it, if there's anything there) and see if that lets things install. If not, you'll need to convert the disk to Dynamic partitions, and see if that works instead.

If you have a spare drive around, you'll probably have a much easier time of it. Borrow one from a friend if you don't have one. There's a full walkthrough [here](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/07/23/dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7-on-a-computer-with-2-hard-drives/) for dual disk dual booting.

Comment: .thanks for the comment.i will try what u said regarding deleting e partition,but i haven't deleted a partition before ,wont the free space merge with other partition, and as for changing to dynamic won't it ruin the whole purpose because last time i accidently changed all the disk to dynamic and was unable to run win 7.

Comment: .also are you certain regarding creating primary drives ,i searched online and found this link [link] (http://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-dual-boot-mode-windows/) and here he didn't create primaries at all.

Comment: ,during installation what would happen if i choose lvm setup instead of something else option,(can it cause data loss).

Comment: @David A, and i dont have a working dvd drive and use usb, also one more thing ,i never get the option of installing alongside win its always repalce existing os and others.

Comment: thanks for the support and suggestion regarding removal of e partition,did the same ,didn't actually wanted that but there was no choice since besides 3 partitions(c,d,e) another reserved memory was also primary partition,so unallocated entire e ,and then created /,home,and swap partitions.and everything went well,and win 7 is also loading fine.

Comment: Awesome. Congratulations on your perseverance. When working with Linux, perseverance is the one thing everyone MUST have, and it is usually well rewarded.  If my original answer was what helped you out, please mark it as the accepted answer. I don't believe your question is a duplicate as someone else suggested. You had a different, more specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't try to set the partition sizes or format said partitions for Ubuntu.  Ubuntu's installer will do that for itself.  It will help you to partition the drive and it will format the partition in its own ext4 format, not NTFS.

(I'm cooking dinner or this might be more complete.  I may come back later with more tips.  Please feel free to comment.)

Comment: ,would definitely like ur suggestion regarding my problem,i like linux and used to install mint,ubuntu in college days but all inside win 7 but never alongside.i even signed up for linux course on edx hoping they might also explain installing but no use.Waiting for reply.

Comment: ,during installation what would happen if i choose lvm setup instead of something else option,(can it cause data loss).

Comment: and i dont have a working dvd drive and use usb, also one more thing ,i never get the option of installing alongside win its always repalce existing os and others.

Comment: Very odd.  I rarely see anything go terribly wrong when leaving Ubuntu to its own regarding installation arrangement.  Often the complaint is that the user would have made the swap drive larger than Ubuntu chooses to.  Other times newbs retry installation of Ubuntu four times and end up with four Ubuntu partitions on the same drive, but in all cases the windows partition is left unharmed.  PS:  re: "something else"  Something else puts the ball in your court regarding partitions and in your case might be perfectly safe.  Windows users sometimes assume "windows" means "personal data". (oops!)

Comment: ,Thanks for the support,eventually had to do away with one partition since their were already 4 primaries ,the installation went fine with manual partitioning and win 7 is also booting up fine.                         Just out of curiosity wanted to know ,if the plan to install another linux distro in that case while installing the same i would have to select the / and swap for formatting leaving the /home as it is,will this do ?